# ActiveAdmin with has_many problem; undefined method 'new_record?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, admin, has-many, formtastic, activeadmin

I'm trying to customise a ActiveAdmin form for a Recipe model that has a has_many relationship with Step.

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :steps
end

class Step < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_list :scope => :recipe

  belongs_to :recipe
end
```

I have the following in my ActiveAdmin file with relation to this:

```
form do |f|
  f.has_many :steps do |ing_f|
    ing_f.inputs
  end
end
```

The following error is thrown when I try to load the form:

> undefined method `new_record?' for nil:NilClass

I've isolated it so far to the has_many method but I'm lost past this. Any advice and help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 169, accepted):

go to your Recipe model and add the following line

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :steps
```

The line is required by formtastic, not active admin. Check https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic for formtastic documentation

Answer (score 2):

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :step_attributes

    has_many :steps

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :steps

end
```